# Clip-path for internal and external SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a triangle using internal and external SVG.

However for some reason it won't work.

I tried to use this tool here: http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

and get it's "POINTS" coordinates to create a perfect clip  TRIANGLE on my internal and external SVG but no luck.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <figure class="clip-holder">
    <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/nintchdbpict000244881006.jpg" class="clip-svg-inline" width="200" height="200">
    <figcaption>Inline SVG</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="clip-holder">
    <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/nintchdbpict000244881006.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    <figcaption>External SVG</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div> 

<svg class="clip-svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="triangle" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" >
      <polygon points="120 263,325 262,222 42"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.clip-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px;
}

.clip-css {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.clip-svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clip-svg-inline {
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#triangle");
  clip-path: url("#triangle");
}



.clip-svg-external {
  -webkit-clip-path: url("https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/nintchdbpict000244881006.jpgt");
  clip-path: url("https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/nintchdbpict000244881006.jpg");
}
```

Am i making any mistakes?

Here's the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/stjtudvj/

(show me jsfiddle solution for better understanding)

Comment: A clip-path must point to a clipPath element, pointing to a jpeg file is invalid. Also there's no triangle element in the CSS file, it's in the html file so a local #triangle reference won't find it.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix it? Any resolution for both internal and external SVG? I am really stuck Robert.

Comment: Point the clip-path to a clipPath element.

Comment: How can you show me the JSFIDDLE please?

Comment: "local #triangle reference won't find it" what do you mean?

Comment: Is there a way you can pinpoint exactly what I've been missing. I know I'm kinda ridiculous for not understanding. Newbie here.

Comment: Point the clip-path to a **clipPath** element and not to a jpeg file.

Comment: What file contains the element with the id triangle? Is that the CSS file? It isn't is it? #triangle in your CSS file will not find the triangle as it's in a different file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115194/discussion-between-kimberly-wright-and-robert-longson).

Comment: These are *clipPath* elements: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Anzeige/clip-path#Grundformen_.28basic_shapes.29. There is an example too, which pretty much looks like what you try to accomplish: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Anzeige/clip-path#Anwendungsbeispiel. --- So basically you apply a your predefined shape (e.g. by using you linked generator) to an image using the CSS-property `clipPath` (which describes the shape).

Comment: You can use the **`clip-path`** property to supply an actual shape (like I mentioned above) or via `url()`. Latter is pointing either to an existing SVG in the DOM ("internal SVG") or to an actual URL containing an SVG ("external SVG"). --- An example you can find here: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/GJpxXY

Comment: I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stjtudvj/2/ --- Please keep in mind, that not all browsers support this property fully yet (http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Answer (score 1):

The actual value of the `clip-path` property has to be an SVG clipPath. It can never be an image (like a JPG). It always to be the actual shape that should be applied on your image.

For example these are clipPath elements: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Anzeige/clip-path#Grundformen_.28basic_shapes.29.
There is an example too, which pretty much looks like what you try to accomplish: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Anzeige/clip-path#Anwendungsbeispiel.

So basically you apply a your predefined shape (e.g. by using your linked generator) to an image using the CSS-property clipPath (which describes the shape). Like this:

**HTML**

```
<img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" id="triangle" />
```

**CSS**

```
img#triangle {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

You can use the `clip-path` property to supply an actual shape (like I mentioned above) or via url(). Latter is pointing either to an existing SVG in the DOM ("internal SVG") or to an actual URL containing an SVG ("external SVG").
An example you can find here: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/GJpxXY

Based on that example I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stjtudvj/2/
I fixed the inline `#triangle` SVG. Your values were exceeding the image dimensions.

Please keep in mind, that not all browsers support this property fully yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: how about the external SVG?

Comment: If I tell you "Get me to your car." you won't just show me an image of your car or an image of your house, you'd get me to your actual physical car. And that's what this `clip-path` is about. The value of this property should always be an actual shape - whether you diretcly define it as it's value (like in my example) or you reference an SVG containing such a shape (like a shortlink on your Windows desktop isn't the actual file itself, but clicking on it works like clicking on the actual file).

Comment: The `clip-path` property is not fully supported by browsers (see the link I supplied at the bottom of my answer) - that's why "external SVG" doesn't seem to work in Chrome or Firefox. Just use the example I linked (the Codepen one) and test it in multiple browsers you want to support, so you know what works in all of them. --- As it seems Chrome 51 and Opera 38 support "CSS" and "inline SVG", Firefox 47 only supports "inline SVG", IE11 doesn't support it at all.